# NameError in Static_pages#home, undefined local variable or method `activity'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using the PublicActivity ruby gem and I'm getting this error message

This is happening inside `/views/activities/_index.html.erb`

```
<li>

  <% if activity.trackable_type == "Micropost" %>
     <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner if activity.owner %> posted
  <% else %>
   <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner if activity.owner %> made a comment on <%= link_to activity.recipient_id %>
  <% end %>

</li>
```

However, when I include this line, it works fine

```
<li>
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <% if activity.trackable_type == "Micropost" %>
     <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner if activity.owner %> posted
  <% else %>
   <%= link_to activity.owner.name, activity.owner if activity.owner %> made a comment on <%= link_to activity.recipient_id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</li>
```

I added `<% @activities.each do |activity| %>` above. It works without the error but the problem is that, in the view the activities are repeated inside the same list.

This is where the `activities/_index.html.erb` is getting called

My `views\shared\_feed.html.erb`

```
  <%= render partial: 'activities/index', collection: @activities %>
```

My activities controller

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
    @activity = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc")
  end

end
```

Comment: Why do you have two variables in your controller that are the same thing?

Comment: I was trying to fix another issue which I'm still working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using render :partial with the collection makes a variable with the name of the partial available. So one option is; in your partial, change activity for index, as in:

```
<li>
  <% if index.trackable_type == "Micropost" %>
```

Even better, rename your partial to _activity.html.erb, and don't change anything inside. That will be much more clear.